# MySQL failing to establish a connection

Tags: php, mysql, database

I recently created a webpage, while using an usbWebserver, so basically a local server.
Yesterday, I have purchased a domain and hosting, and I wanted to move my files onto the server.

I have changed my username, password and url, however I cannot get the mysql_connect to work.

```
<?php

    $mysqlhost = "mysql04.totaalholding.nl"; 
    $user = "a";
    $passwd = "";


    $mysql = mysql_connect($mysqlhost, mysql_real_escape_string($user), mysql_real_escape_string($passwd));
    if (!$mysql) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $db_selected = mysql_select_db('a_turfjes', $mysql);
    if (!$db_selected) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

?>
```

The above code is how I connect to the database, which should work. (please note that a is not my username and neither is my password empty).

These are the properties of the database:

DATABASE:  a_turfjes

Extern MySQL Host: mysql04.totaalholding.nl

Users: a_admin

I am not quite sure which username to use should I use the username and password from cpanel (which is required to access PHPMyAdmin), or the username and password, which is the user of the database itsself.

I'd like some help on this error. When accessing my index.php (which includes db.php (which is the file above)), I receive the following errors:

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/a/public_html/turfjes/db.php on line 8

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/a/public_html/turfjes/db.php on line 8

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/a/public_html/turfjes/db.php on line 8

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/a/public_html/turfjes/db.php on line 8

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'root'@'www30.totaalholding.nl' (using password: NO) in /home/a/public_html/turfjes/db.php on line 8
Could not connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'www30.totaalholding.nl' (using password: NO)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the username and password of the database itself not the cpanel.

Test connection using:

```
$mysql_host = "localhost"; # Usually doesn"t need modified
$mysql_db = "a_turfjes"; # Database name
$mysql_user = ""; # Username
$mysql_pass = ""; # Password
$link = mysql_connect ($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass);
if (!$link) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
```

If successful, access records:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM TableName";
$result = mysql_db_query ($dbname, $query, $link);
```

Comment: Shouldn't localhost be changed to my external host? As the database is hosted on another site than my own.

Comment: @user1390504 Yes you should change that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the database username and password. If the database is hosted in another server please give the host name to that server name